Restarting LVM with a new lvm.conf
I'd like to turn off event_activation while modifying an unmounted drive (the udev rules otherwise run vgchange when a change in the unmounted drive is detected). The man page says that "lvm.conf is loaded during the initialisation phase of lvm". Can I reload lvm to force a re-read of lvm.conf?
If I set event_activation to 0 in lvm.conf and run lvm dumpconfig it does report the new value, but presumably doesn't act on it. If necessary, I could just turn off LVM instead (the system is rebooted after modifying the drive) - is there a way to do that? Oddly, adding nolvm to the kernel options doesn't seem to affect this issue - vgchange is still run when the drive is modified.

Can you be more specific about modifying an unmounted drive? What kind of modification exactly? And by drive are you talking about a PV or a disk that consists of a PV-partition? It sounds like you are using an older version of LVM. It shouldn't happen with recent enough versions of LVM (that is not modified "downstream"). vgchange would only be run if the udev event (of a PV) is add (instead of change). And there's no reload / re-read needed because the pvscan command runs that determine whether vgchange should be run will just check the setting in lvm.conf directly.

@TomYan: I'm writing a Linux image to a plain unmounted "disk" - rotary or SSD, completely over-writing it. The image contains multiple partitions, with LVM. This is a recent LVM (2.03.26(2)), but Arch (actually SystemRescue) so I think there may be mods. Bizarrely, when the image is completely written, vgchange runs, even though there was no actual 'event'.

@TomYan: interesting pvscan comment - I'll try it now.

Well it sounds like something that would trigger udev "add" event(s) of PV(s) to me. Still, with event_activation=0 in lvm.conf the corresponding VG(s) should not be activated. (You may check /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/69-dm-lvm.rules. It actually explicitly mentions that. Make sure you don't have any rule files that you have "forgotten" in /etc/udev/rules.d/ though.) Have you been observing the opposite behavior?

@TomYan: If I mod the drive-write script to set event_activation = 0 in lvm.conf before over-writing the drive then the drive write completes without any interference from vgchange, so it look like you're right. If you want to do an answer of some sort I'll accept it.

With recent enough version of LVM, vgchange might only be run if the udev event (of a PV) is add (instead of change). (The approach makes sure that it would only be run when all the PVs of a VG are found.) And there's no reload / re-read needed because the pvscan command runs (triggered with 69-dm-lvm.rules) that determine whether vgchange should be run will just check the setting in lvm.conf directly.
It sounds to me that what you would do would trigger add udev event(s) of PV(s). Still, with event_activation=0 in lvm.conf, the corresponding VG(s) should not be activated.
Note that if your root filesystem resides on an LV, you would want to be careful with event_activation=0, because that could prevent your root filesystem from being available. It might not happen right away after the modification lvm.conf because the initramfs would contain its own copy, so the undesired behavior would only kick it once there is a initramfs regeneration (e.g. when there is a kernel update). But certainly, that won't be a problem if you are running a live system (i.e. the modification is "volatile").
